# HTC Evo's Facebook Sync Reboots Phone

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-evo, facebook

After a week's worth of troubleshooting, I have discovered that enabling any sort of account synchronization for "Facebook for HTC Sense" will cause the phone to randomly soft-reboot.  I believe this happens if either "Sync live feed" **or** "Sync contacts" is checked in "Accounts & sync".

I would like to have my facebook feed available to the facebook widget and I like having my contacts' pictures automatically updated when they change their profile picture.  However, the random reboots are extremely annoying and it also causes a ridiculous amount of battery drain.  One last symptom is that the stock messaging app will continuously scroll you to the bottom of a conversation when you attempt to scroll up.  Is there any way I can get the best of both worlds?

I am running 1.47.651.1 (Android 2.1).  Will upgrading to 2.2 fix this issue?  I haven't upgraded yet because currently their isn't a way to root 2.2 and I'm still on the fence about that.

Answer (score 2):

Good work on not upgrading to 2.2 yet for purposes of rooting!

As for your specific issue, you mention it happens when attempting to sync with facebook and then mention the reboots are random. Are they random or a cause of a specific action? My guess is they would be more random since as far as I know few people have problems with FB. Although there was an issue on HTC servers that caused FB sync to stop working awhile back. I do not think that issue caused any phones to reboot though.

Where did you buy your phone and did you get it brand new or used or refurb? With random reboots I would think you could take it into Sprint and have them look at it if you bout it new, since the likelihood you caused the reboot issue is slim.

Have you looked at the XDA Forums for help? There are a lot of Evo users there and they may be able to help, even if you aren't rooted.

Also I would recommend rooting, check the XDA forums. I don't think a single custom ROM has any issues with FB syncing. Not that rooting will necessarily fix your issues.

Comment: I have turned off enable always on mobile data to save battery (works rather well).  However, when that is off and facebook sync is on, the phone reboots randomly.  Change either of those options and no reboots.  I've had 2 Evo's and both had this problem.  Both were acquired near launch.  It's a problem with Facebook unless one of the specs for turning off always on mobile data was to randomly reboot the phone =)

Comment: LOL that would be an odd feature for sure. Was there anything on XDA along these lines? I would still check out that site. If you go to Setting > About phone > Software information what do you have under "Android version" and "Software number"? Could be a bug in your version of Android with version of sync and facebook.

You could try going into Settings > Applications and find Facebook. Then click on it, clear cache, and reboot. Clearing the cache for apps sometimes helps. If that doesn't help, you could try upgrading or reinstalling facebook.